# Conditionally assign values to a Pandas column

Tags: python, pandas

I need to set a variable in Column B based on value in Column A as in :

ABC     1
PQR -
ABC -
PQR     -
ABC -
PQR     -

In my data, against some values of Column A I have a '1' set in column B. But the issue is it is against only the first occurrence. Like for 'ABC' above, '1' is set only for the first occurrence.

I need to set the '1' for all such remaining values.
PS - There are a lot of entries so I can't hard-code values like 'For all ABC set column B to 1'

I've tried the following logic -

```
#Filter out entries with a '1' set
df_one = df_Consolidated[df_Consolidated['Val'] == 1]

#Store these values in a list
list_l2 = []
for s in df_one:
    list_l2.append(df_one['Text String'])

#Check in the dataframe column once again iterating over the list
```

But I don't think this is the best or the correct approach to do this. I'm looking for a simple yet effective solution.

Comment: I think simpliest is `df.loc[df["A"] == "ABC", "B"] = 1`

Comment: @jezrael he said only first occurrence of the Text  has value 1, so using "ABC" is making that static. which won't be able to solve for other occurrence of Text like "ABC"

Comment: OK, so change `df.loc[df['Text'].isin((df.loc[df['val'] == '1', 'Text'])), 'val'] = '1'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

data(test.csv):

```
Text,val
ABC,1
PQR,-
ABC,-
PQR,-
ABC,-
PQR,-
```

code:

```
df = pd.read_csv('test.csv')
df.loc[df['Text'].isin((df[df['val'] == '1']['Text'])), 'val'] = '1'
print(df)
```

output:

```
  Text val
0  ABC   1
1  PQR   -
2  ABC   1
3  PQR   -
4  ABC   1
5  PQR   -
```

---

explanation:

here `df[df['val'] == '1']['Text']` will get all Text has `val = '1'`

`df['Text'].isin((df[df['val'] == '1']['Text'])` will check for each row has Text in `df[df['val'] == '1']['Text']` it will return `Boolean`

like

```
0     True
1    False
2     True
3    False
4     True
5    False
```

and `df.loc` to assign val to 1

Comment: I'm getting Invalid Type Comparison : TypeError

Comment: Solved it, it was just that '1' had to be 1

Comment: i have to use `'1'` because i have used csv import and all other values in `val` column are string type so pandas will automatically convert that `val = 1` to string type